# What is the best way to pass a boolean prop through a react useEffect component to control a ternary operator?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-operator

I recently learned about props, as I am fairly new to React, and am trying to implement them in places to reduce the amount of repeated code in each page of a web app I am building.

Originally, I had the following useEffect and useState placed above each return to simply control if something is available on the page or not.

```
  

    const [waiting, setWaiting] = useState(false);
      useEffect(() => {
        setWaiting(true) 
      }
    
      return ( 
        <> 
         { waiting ? ( *displays a "Coming Soon" page* ) : ( *displays the webpage* ) 
        </>
      )
```

Which ran well and I could simply change the boolean value on the useEffect if I wanted to remove the waiting screen and display the page content.

But this resulted in me repeating that useEffect for every page that had content, which is enough for me to realize I don't have to repeat this code.

So I set up the following component:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const NoPhotos = (props) => {
  //Photos Aren't Ready Yet
  const [waiting, setWaiting] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (waiting) {
      setWaiting(true);
    } else {
      setWaiting(false);
    }
  }, [props.wait, waiting]);
};

export default NoPhotos;
```

And I replace the "waiting" from the original ternary operator, with the NoPhotos component, as follows:

```
 return ( 
        <> 
         { <NoPhotos wait={true} ? ( *displays a "Coming Soon" page* ) : ( *displays the webpage* ) 
        </>
      )
```

But I noticed that regardless of what boolean I put in the "wait={}", it doesn't change and always shows "true".

Is there a way to make it so the boolean value that is passed in "wait=" controls the state?

Comment: 1. Your code is **if waiting is true, set waiting to true**. 2. Components have to return jsx, your component returns nothing. 3. It's unclear to me why you even have this `useEffect` here instead of rendering things by default

Comment: My goal is to make the useEffect it's own component that I can set the boolean value as a prop so I don't have to repeat the useEffect code through out the pages. If there's a simpler way to do it, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

A hook like this can be helpful:

```
function useWait(setWaiting) {
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setWaiting(false);
    }, 1000);
  }, [setWaiting]);
}
```

Usage:

```
const [waiting, setWaiting] = useState(true);
useWait(setWaiting);

return (
  <>
    <p>{waiting ? "Coming Soon" : "the webpage"}</p>
  </>
);
```

[image: Edit adoring-platform-6exy80]

But I would rather use something like this:

```
function useWait() {
  const [waiting, setWaiting] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setWaiting(false);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return waiting;
}
```

or this:

```
function Wait({ loader, content }) {
  const [waiting, setWaiting] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setWaiting(false);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return <>{waiting ? loader : content}</>;
}
```

Usage:

```
const waiting = useWait(true);

return (
  <>
    <p>{waiting ? "Coming Soon" : "the webpage"}</p>
    <p>
      <Wait loader="Coming soon" content="the webpage" />
    </p>
  </>
);
```

[image: Edit distracted-haibt-pl1reo]

Comment: I like the second option alot, thanks!